# How to deal with NoneType error in Python?

Tags: python, nonetype

I have only picked up coding and Python in the past week so this question may seem obvious.

I am trying to create a card game. I have already created my deck of cards and now I'm trying to make a function to remove a card from the deck and to test that I am printing out the deck of cards.

However, when I remove a random card from the deck and then try to print out the properties of the remaining cards in the deck I receive an error.
I created a class called Card with attributes name, value, suit
I took out parts of the code which were very long and not exactly relevant.
I have a list of all my cards called the_deck
I tried to account for the error with

"if the_deck[i] is None:continue:"

but that doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code and then the error.

```
def pick_a_card():
    a = random.choice(the_deck)
    print(a.name + " of " + a.suit)
    the_deck = the_deck.remove(a)
    i = 0
    while i <= 51:
        if the_deck[i] is None:
            continue
        else:
            print(the_deck[i].name + " of " + the_deck[i].suit)
        i+=1
pick_a_card()
```

The error I get is

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

This error comes from removing a card from the deck. The rest of the function has no errors.

How do I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: `remove` is an in-place operation. Do not assign the result back to `the_deck` because it returns `None`.

Comment: The error means that ``the_deck`` is ``None``, not that ``the_deck[i]`` is None.

Comment: @alaniwi so how should I properly permanently remove a card from the_deck?

Comment: Use only `the_deck.remove(a)`. Thus, remove `the_deck =`

Comment: @Ronald Would that permanently change `the_deck`? I tried doing that earlier but it didn't seem to permanently change it. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @MartinChapman Yes, as Ronald says.

Comment: Try this to see the difference: `lst = [5,4,3,2,1]  newlst = sort(lst)` newlst is the sorted list, but lst is unchanged. OR `lst = [5,4,3,2,1]  lst.sort()`  Now `lst` itself has been changed.

Comment: Numerous correct answers were given to you, but you haven't accepted any as a solution or cast any votes. Please consider doing **your** part and reward the effort that was invested in you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your data looks like but this is an example of how to remove a random from a list that may help.

```
the_deck = [*range(1, 53, 1)]

def remove_val(the_deck):
    a = random.choice(the_deck)
    the_deck.remove(a)
    print('Value removed:', a)
    print('New deck:', the_deck)
```

A point of note in your example is that, that @alaniwi pointed out, is that should not re-assign `the_deck = the_deck.remove(a)` rather it should read `the_deck.remove(a)`. Also, you are not handling the fact that `len(the_deck)` reduces by 1 every time you remove a card.

Comment: He shouldn't worry about the number of cards remaining. By switching the `while` with a `for` he can iterate over whatever is left in the deck.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to every issue:

1. treat `remove()` as an action, not a parser
2. use fstrings to concat string data
3. separate game logic from diagnostics
4. name things what they are
5. use a `for` loop to iterate the deck so you never have to worry about how many cards there are

The below script is an example of how to implement the solution list

```
from collections import namedtuple
import random

#a simple deck generator so this example is complete
Card = namedtuple('Card', 'face suit')

def deck_generator():
    faces = [*list(map(str, range(2,11))), 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    suits = ['♠', '♥', '♦', '♣']
    deck  = []

    for s in suits:
        for f in faces:
            deck.append(Card(f, s))
            
    return deck
    
Deck = deck_generator()
#end deck generator

the_deck = Deck[:] #unique copy so you don't have to keep making the deck

#game logic
def pick_a_card():
    card = random.choice(the_deck)
    the_deck.remove(card) #action not parser
    return card #not 'a'

#diagnostic separated from game logic       
def viewdeck():
    deck = ''
    for card in the_deck: #number of remaining cards is irrelevant
        deck = f'{deck}{card.face}{card.suit}, ' #fstring
    print(deck)
    
        
card = pick_a_card() 
print(f'{card.face}{card.suit}') #fstring
#5♣

viewdeck()  
#2♠, 3♠, 4♠, 5♠, 6♠, 7♠, 8♠, 9♠, 10♠, J♠, Q♠, K♠, A♠, 
#2♥, 3♥, 4♥, 5♥, 6♥, 7♥, 8♥, 9♥, 10♥, J♥, Q♥, K♥, A♥, 
#2♦, 3♦, 4♦, 5♦, 6♦, 7♦, 8♦, 9♦, 10♦, J♦, Q♦, K♦, A♦, 
#2♣, 3♣, 4♣, 6♣, 7♣, 8♣, 9♣, 10♣, J♣, Q♣, K♣, A♣,
```

**Aside**

Most container types have inline methods that work on the container directly. These methods may not return anything. You could perceive this as an action you are telling the container to perform on itself. Knowing if an inline method will or will not have a return comes with experience or a quick trip through some docs. As an example, consider `remove()`, `append()` or `insert()` versus `pop()`. All of these are inline methods, but only `pop()` returns data.

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` list method removes the element passed to by modifying the list. That is, it just modifies the list referenced by the list name. However it returns `None`. If there is no `return` statement in function/method, Python interpreter returns `None`.

To check that `remove` method returns `None`, run the  following code at Python interpreter:

```
>>> a = [1, 2 ,3]
>>> if a.remove(1) == None:
...     print('Returns None')
...
```

the `if` block will be executed.

You can also check what type of error Python will return if you try to index and `int` or `None` object.

```
>>> a = None
>>> a[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: He will never need to check the remove method. He removes a card that he just got from the same deck he is removing from.

Comment: I agree on that. I was trying to give him hints how to explore what's happing in the back stage of python. The idea that a function returns a `None` object even when execution is successful is not easy to grasp by Python beginners.

Comment: I understand, but I opine that better help would be to point the user in the direction of the actual answer. An aside could be appended regarding inline methods and their behavior. Whereas your illustration is not wrong, it is also not exactly clear. I could give an example of a better example and I will append it to my answer above.